# Escape '\' in dynamic content in Azure Data Factory

Tags: db2, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, dynamic-content

I am hitting a query through lookup activity on DB2 Database using ADF.

Query is:
[image]

But when I execute the query the '\' count gets double.
The output is provided in the below screenshot.
[image]

As you can see in the screenshot given, the '\' count gets double.
I need a solution to remove these extra '\' coming in my query.

Answer (score 0):

By default, **backslash** escape character `\` gets doubled when used in the Azure data factory.

Use replace function in your expression to replace double backslash with single backslash.

**Example:**

`@replace('\\abc\\','\\','\')`

[image]

[image]